# How to construct data in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d

I have data in the form of sets and i want convert it into 2D numpy array.
Data is like

```
term = which contains the words
document_number= which has the doc number
tf-idf= which contain the tf-idf of each word with respect to doc in ordered manner
```

I want it should be in 2D numpy array like this

```
            doc1    doc2   doc3....
term1        1        5      6
term2        0        4      1
term3        6        8      10
.
.
```

How should I implement it?

Comment: you are going to need to clarify the input more to get help

Comment: Do you mean a [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)?

Comment: Also, check out pandas DataFrames: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the structure of `tf-idf` is not clear. So I have to make some assumptions about your data structure.

```python
term_len = len(term)
doc_len = len(document_number)
```

So assuming that `tf-idf` is a flat list (not list of lists) where the frequency of the first term in all the documents is in there, then for the second term, and so on.

```
term_freq = numpy.zeros((term_len, doc_len), dtype=int)
for (i, freq) in enumerate(tf_ids):
    term_freq[i // term_len, i % doc_len] = freq
```

If the opposite is true, just turn the modulo and division operation around.

Comment: Your assumption is right but I'm not getting the modulo and division operations used for. Actually I am new to python. Is it for the 2D array titles??

Comment: A 2D array is the same as a matrix. So you have `N` rows and `M` columns. It's dimensions are `N x M`. You have a list that contains `N * M` elements. `enumerate` creates a running index from 0 to `N * M - 1`. We want to map that index to a column and row index. So the modulo lets you cycle through the index quickly whereas the division steps more slowly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I am getting  ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.0,0.1524,0.0,0.45678  error

Comment: Is that a string that contains all those numbers? It's really hard to help without knowing your data exactly. If it is a string you can split it on the comma and then transform each to a float: `[float(num) for num in data_string.split(",")]`.

Comment: I want output as
`[['TERM' 'TF-IDF1  ' 'TF-IDF2  ' ..., 'TF-IDF11  ' '' '']
 ['acquire' '0.0' '0.0' ..., '0.027882503172' '' '']
 ['act' '0.0' '0.0' ..., '0.0' '' '']
 ..., 
 ['year' '0.0' '0.0' ..., '0.0' '' '']
 ['yet' '0.0' '0.0' ..., '0.0' '' '']
 ['york' '0.0757230086146' '0.0' ..., '0.0' '' '']]`
You can see how my data is in the output